# Why are system calls so much slower in Python compared to C++?

Tags: python, c++, performance

I have 2 code snippets that are identical in the sense that they complete the same task. One code was written in python, the other in C++. All they do is call an executable that generates an ASCII file. In C++, I use the `system()` command to call the executable. In Python, I have used many things including `os.system` `subprocess.call` `subprocess.popen`.

I realize that C++ is a compiled language while Python is interpreted, and therefore, Python calls have more overhead. But the C++ code does the job nearly 100 times faster than the Python code. The C++ took about 0.004 seconds but the Python took around 0.35 seconds.

Even a simple `pwd` command takes more than 10 times longer with Python than it does with C++. If the overhead is what is slowing the Python code down, is there a faster option in Python than what I have already tried?

Here is the Python code:

```
from os import system
from time import time

t0 = time();
system("pwd");
print "duration: ",time()-t0;
```

Here is the same thing in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
double diff(timespec start, timespec end) { return (end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)/1e9; }

int main()
{
    timespec t0, t1;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, & t0);
    system("pwd");
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, & t1);
    
    std::cout << "duration: " << diff(t0,t1) << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

I used GCC to compile the C++ code. You have to use the `-lrt` option to get the code to compile correctly.

You can run the code yourself. My timing methods could be wrong. But if they are correct, then the Python script takes more than 10 times as long to execute the `pwd` command compared to the C++ executable.

Comment: Yes, edit your question to include code, compilation command, timing. Don't confuse the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function with [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: The Python interpreter does quite a lot of initialization at startup. If you are just timing how long it takes to run this script *including starting the Python interpreter* that's why.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also indicated your OS, execution environment, Python version, timing method.

Comment: @kindall on my machine it takes the Python interpreter at most 0.05 seconds to start up

Comment: i edited my post to include code. can someone compare the times on their machines?

Comment: If the "10 times as long" is the difference of a few ms, then that's the initialization of the Python interpreter. If the executed command takes any reasonably long amount of time, then the C++ and Python code would take essentially the same amount of time. If you are executing a **new Python process** in a loop in some external script, that's your problem. Internalize the loop into the Python script.

Comment: @oregon, i dont think thats true. i have 2 codes that call the same fortran executable. c++ takes ~0.004 seconds to execute while the python script takes ~0.35 seconds. its more than 80 times longer.

Comment: I'm still not seeing your numbers. I ran your new python example and got `duration: 0.001123...`.

Comment: okay, and the c++ executable takes 0.000131...

Comment: I'm testing on python 2.7.3, kubuntu 13.04.

Comment: i have the old python 2.4.3 and it takes 0.0028 seconds for my python interpreter to get the job done. either way, the c++ code is 10 times faster (or more)

Comment: By the time we get down to .000x values, 10 times faster is pretty small and i think we can chalk it up to more heavy lifting in interpreted languages and even differences in how time values are read. For projects where this level of timing makes a difference, go with C!

Comment: i agree but why is there an even greater difference for system calls that take longer to execute compared to my `pwd` example? as i noted earlier, i have 2 codes that call a fortran executable (i dont know fortran and i cant rewrite the program). i cant provide all the code here but i have tested the codes in a similar manner and i find that the c++ executable is almost 100 times faster! you would think that the difference in speed would decrease going from a simple system call to something "more complicated".

Answer (score 1):

C 'exec' call executes the program directly.

While the Python 'system' call first executes bash, that executes the program in question.

Comment: The OP said he was using the `system` function which also calls the shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `execvp` directly in python

```
import os

binary = "ls"
options = [binary, "-l"]

newpid = os.fork()
if newpid == 0:
     # we are in the child process
     os.execvp(binary, options)
     os._exit(1)

os.wait()
print "executed", " ".join(options)
```

Comment: for whatever reason, the command is executed properly but the rest of the python script that comes after the `os.execvp` command is ignored. the executable is called and works fine. but even a simple `print "here"` after `os.execvp` is ignored

Comment: That's because `execvp` replaces the current process, in this case, the Python interpreter. You can `fork` and then `exec`. See my edit.

Comment: i used your suggestion in my code but the last line `print "executed", " ".join(options)` does not seem to execute. my terminal is hung. as soon as i press enter, the process terminates and nothing is printed to the terminal

Comment: What you were seeing was contention on stdout. I updated my answer to use `os.wait()`

Comment: that works great. thanks. unfortunately, the execution is not any faster. it still takes the same amount of time to execute as subprocess methods. thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 1):

I cooked up a little script and execution time was much faster than what you are seeing.

```
td@timsworld2:~/tmp/so$ cat nothing.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ['python', '-V'] if 'py' in sys.argv else ['pwd']
if 'shell' in sys.argv:
    subprocess.call(' '.join(cmd), shell=True)
else:
    subprocess.call(cmd)


td@timsworld2:~/tmp/so$ time ./nothing.py
/home/td/tmp/so

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.008s
td@timsworld2:~/tmp/so$ time python nothing.py
/home/td/tmp/so

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.004s
td@timsworld2:~/tmp/so$ time ./nothing.py py
Python 2.7.3

real    0m0.022s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.000s
td@timsworld2:~/tmp/so$ time ./nothing.py sh
/home/td/tmp/so

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.004s
td@timsworld2:~/tmp/so$
```

Comment: so the python script takes ~0.02 seconds to execute. have you tried the same thing in c++? i use linux and a simple `pwd` command with python takes ~0.02 seconds while the same command using c++ is more like 0.002 seconds

Comment: @rolb - good question - I was interested in the python exec time with and without shell on a couple of representative binaries. If you post an example C program, i'll give it a whirl. By the time we get to .02 verses .002, we can blame the python setup time.